# engdemo.c on Mac OSX - Can't start MATLAB engine

Tags: macos, matlab, matlab-engine

I'm trying to build and run the Matlab Engine example "engdemo.c" using the [instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/build-unix-engine-example.html) from Mathworks.  When I try to run it with the command `!./engdemo`, I'm getting the following error:

```
matlab: Command not found.
Can't start MATLAB engine
```

I have not found a solution to this in other relevant StackOverflow posts (e.g. [matlab engine “Can't start MATLAB engine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622538/matlab-engine-cant-start-matlab-engine) or [How solve the “Can't start MATLAB engine” command? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622538/matlab-engine-cant-start-matlab-engine))

I have csh installed at /bin/csh (checked this by typing `which csh`).

I have Matlab on my PATH variable, and I have set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable according to the [Mathworks instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-and-running-engine-applications-on-unix-operating-systems.html) for Mac OSX.  Here are the lines I have included in my .bash_profile to set these environment variables:

```
# Settings for Matlab Engine using Apple XCode
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/sys/os/maci64:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Ultimately I would like to build a C program that uses Matlab scripts (ideally building with XCode), but it's frustrating to have trouble even getting the demo to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using [these instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101334-how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-matlab-engine-program-on-unix-linux-mac) from Mathworks.  The key difference is the way I compiled engdemo.c with mex.  Before I was using `mex -client engine engdemo.c` (see above), but I would get errors when trying to run the demo from either the Matlab prompt or from my shell.

Following that article, I changed to compiling with the following: `mex -f /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/engopts.sh ./engdemo.c`.  At first this threw an error saying that it couldn't find SDK "macosx10.7" (note that I'm using OSX 10.9). I looked in engopts.sh and found a lot of references to macosx10.7.

Following [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103904-can-i-use-xcode-5-as-my-c-or-c-compiler-in-matlab-8-1-r2013a-or-matlab-8-2-r2013b), I edited engopts.sh by changing all references to macosx10.7 to macosx10.8. (Note that even though I have osx10.9, I also have the 10.8 SDK, which you can see by typing `find`xcode-select -print-path`-name MacOSX10.8.sdk`.  I decided to use 10.8 because in that article someone said that other things broke when they used 10.9, but I have not checked this myself yet.)

After making these changes, I re-ran `mex -f /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/engopts.sh ./engdemo.c`, and it worked.  Running ./engdemo from the shell ran the program successfully.  This still seems very hackish to me.